# Magento 2.2.9 - Admin page error console-logger.js

Tags: magento2, admin, javascript

I did an update from Magento 2.2.7 to 2.2.9 and now when I want to access to the admin page I have an error message :

*main.ERROR: Unable to resolve the source file for 'adminhtml/Magento/backend/en_US/Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-logger.js' [] []*

Can you help me?